# Fastest way to see new question on stackoverflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions

Currently i use this link to see newest question's with jQuery tag

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/jquery?tab=newest

I need to refresh the page soo frequently to get new question as they are posted,
Is their any automatic/faster way to get to the new question.

Comment: What's the urgency? Why do you need to see them sooooo quickly?

Comment: Well, with StackOverflowGOLDPlusUltra2013 you can subscribe and have access to questions before they're *even posted to the site*. Yours for only $19.99/month!

Comment: @tombull89 the 2014 edition is out now ... You get Diamond badges

Comment: @tombull89 - Is that the subscription that comes with the expert chat?

Comment: @tombull89 I just got subscribed to that _StackOverflowGOLDPlusUltra2013_ for $19.99 , I am still not able to access those question's.

Comment: @Oded, sorry that's the PlantinumPlusExtraUltimate. Yours for $29.99 and you get the questions 17 minutes before they're posted.

Comment: What I don't understand is why a JAVAGeek wants to watch [tag:jquery] questions.

Comment: @Oded He wants to play Fastest Gun In The West.  The Jquery tag in particular has a lot of low-hanging fruit that gets answered very, very quickly.  In cases like this, getting a 10 second jump on the opposition can be the difference between that sweet, sweet accepted rep and the dry dust of nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Ok you want the *fastest* way ? 
The tools are there you just need to know how to use them.

[image]

There you see you have 2 new questions so no matter what you are doing you know you have 2 questions waiting for you.

If you are on Meta, you can always use this tool on which you can click !

[image]

If you are not fast enough with these tools, you can alway go the classic way

- Go to the main page.
- Press `F5`
- Repeat

Comment: That, or wait until you get `1 question with new activity` (or some such, forget the wording)

Comment: You're right ! I'll update my post thanks !

Comment: @Telthien I don't think Stack Overflow has that particular functionality.

Comment: @Telthien StackOverflow does not have that option because of its high number of questions asked. It does work however if you are only watching a specific list of tags. :)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar This *is* available for Stack Overflow, but only on tag pages (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).